# Move cell based on info & place to next available cell

Tags: google-sheets

In a tab I have an SKU column & and an EMAIL column. I need to move the email cell based on the SKU next to it to a new tab and place it in the next available column following the SKU number that matches.

I'm trying to place each new order email in the next available edition (we sell limited editions of 25).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1utwtpSgBVaCVuP1BnYsIAXFa674FDZylrOEcyR-6syM/edit#gid=329839874 i need the info from TAB2 to go to TAB3

Comment: answer updated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `VLOOKUP`. example:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

---

### update 1

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, {'TAB2'!B:B, 'TAB2'!A:A}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

use in E2 cell and drag to the right:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP($C$2:$C, FILTER({'TAB2'!$B:$B, 'TAB2'!$A:$A}, 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH('TAB2'!$A:$A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $D:D)))), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: would this add the email on the rows with edition 2 if the SKU is repeated? For ex. Email1 and Email3 have the same SKU. Email1 would go on 1 and then Email3 on 2 and so on, to automatically assign an edition to the purchase.

Comment: For some reason this seems to skip over certain emails. Is there something I can do about it? Some emails are repeated in the orders, would that be a reason?

Comment: @Spacey formula takes emails from D column and excludes it from every next column (E) so yes, thats the reason

Comment: @Spacey see your sheet for alternative: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1utwtpSgBVaCVuP1BnYsIAXFa674FDZylrOEcyR-6syM/edit#gid=329839874